# Get all "price" and "type" values from nested JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to get all `price` and `type` from the following JSON in C#. Can any one help me with this?

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "21": {
            "cheapest_room": {
                "website": {},
                "corp": {
                    "price": 3174.08,
                    "type": "MAPLE"
                }
            },
            "availability": 6,
            "tcr_multiplier": 1
        },
        "756": {
            "cheapest_room": {
                "website": {},
                "corp": {}
            },
            "availability": false
        },
        "1070": {
            "cheapest_room": {
                "website": {},
                "corp": {
                    "price": 2808.05,
                    "type": "OAK"
                }
            },
            "availability": 1,
            "tcr_multiplier": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Do you want them to be **paired together**, i.e. "Find all JSON objects that have both `type` and `price` properties?

Comment: {
        "21": {
            "cheapest_room": {
                "website": {},
                "corp": {
                    "price": 3174.08,
                    "type": "MAPLE"
                }
            },
            "availability": 6,
            "tcr_multiplier": 1
        }

In this "21" is Id so i need id wise Price and Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using JSON.Net, this will produce and dictionary of hotelId and room price.

```
JObject dataJson = JObject.Parse(json);
Dictionary<string, double> prices = dataJson["data"]
                                        .Children<JProperty>()
                                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Name,
                                                      v => Convert.ToDouble(v.Value["cheapest_room"]["corp"]["price"] ?? -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete sample

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main( string[] args )
        {
            var endpoint = new RoomEndpoint( new FakeJsonProvider() );
            var response = await endpoint.GetFooAsync();
            var mydata = response.Data
                .Where( e => e.Value.CheapestRoom?.Corp?.Price != null )
                .Select( e => new { e.Key, Price = e.Value.CheapestRoom.Corp.Price.Value, Type = e.Value.CheapestRoom.Corp.Type } )
                .ToList();

            foreach (var item in mydata)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "{0}-{1}: {2}", item.Key, item.Type, item.Price );
            }
        }
    }

    interface IJsonProvider
    {
        Task<string> GetAsync( string uri );
    }

    class RoomEndpoint
    {
        private readonly IJsonProvider _jsonProvider;

        public RoomEndpoint( IJsonProvider jsonProvider )
        {
            _jsonProvider = jsonProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( jsonProvider ) );
        }
        public async Task<FooResponseData> GetFooAsync()
        {
            var json = await _jsonProvider.GetAsync( "foo" ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FooResponseData>( json );
        }
    }

    class FakeJsonProvider : IJsonProvider
    {
        public Task<string> GetAsync( string uri )
        {
            string json = null;
            switch (uri)
            {
                case "foo":
                    json = json = Properties.Resources.FooResponseJson; // contains the given Json Response
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return Task.FromResult( json );
        }
    }

    class CorpData
    {
        [JsonProperty( "price" )]
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( "type" )]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    class WebsiteData
    {

    }

    class RoomData
    {
        [JsonProperty( "corp" )]
        public CorpData Corp { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( "website" )]
        public WebsiteData Website { get; set; }
    }

    class KeyData
    {
        [JsonProperty( "cheapest_room" )]
        public RoomData CheapestRoom { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( "availibility" )]
        public int? Availability { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( "tcr_multiplier" )]
        public int? TcrMultiplier { get; set; }
    }

    class FooResponseData
    {
        [JsonProperty( "status" )]
        public int Status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty( "data" )]
        public IDictionary<string, KeyData> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JSON Path](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/electToken.htm) provided by [NewtonSoft's JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm), for example:

```
// load & parse the json
var jo = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("test.json"));

// select all 'corp' objects recursively anywhere in the doc
foreach (var tok in jo.SelectTokens("..corp")) 
{
    // extract information (note some of your corp objects don't contain anything)
    var price = tok["price"]?.Value<double>();
    var type = tok["type"]?.Value<string>();
}
```